# Модель данных

Tags: java

Можно ли считать моделью данных этот класс?

```
class Record {
    int id = 0;
    String name = "";
    String telephone = "";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в общем то да это модель данных в довольно общем смысле... Для полноты картины добавил бы конструктор, объявил все члены приватными.

Некоторые, правда, понимают под моделью данных отображение данных в БД - да еще и соблюдением теоремы Бойса-Кодда о нормальности данных, ну да ладно не будем придираться. Да это модель данных представленная с использованием обычных JavaBeans

Answer (score 3):

Все зависит от того, как вы определяете термин "модель данных". Согласно одному из определений  "результат отображения сущности предметной области в терминах данных инструмента разработки называется моделью данных". Если ваш код, отражает сущность предметной области, то это модель данных, если нет - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если все данные - это имя и номер телефона, то можно.